# Accessing function within package gives error "object 'package' not found"

Tags: r, function, package, rstudio

I want to access functions within packages using `package name::function`. The packages are loaded into the session, the data referred to exist, the functions on their own run.

But when using the above, R seems to think that the package is an object. I get the error: `object 'package name' not found`. I seem to be getting this with all packages, at least with `car`, `lme4`, and `brms`.

Example:

`lme4::model <- lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + (1|Vp) + (1|Tgt), data=dat, REML=F)` produces the error above. The error does not occur with the `base` package.

Very recently, I updated RStudio to version 1.2.1335 and it seems to be happening since then. I'm using R version 3.5.0 and Windows 10.

I also tried `package:::function` as suggested in an answer to a similar question, bt it doesn't help.
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us what you are really doing, don't paraphrase.  If the package and function names you are trying to use are not available to others, then substitute base packages that everyone will have.

Comment: Example added. It's really an extremely general problem.

Comment: Highly recommended that you update to R 3.5.3 or to the latest 3.6.1. Both of these will allow you to update packages and install new packages

Comment: `lme4::model <-` should raise a syntax error. Don't use `::` on the left hand side. Do something like `lme4_model <-`. Maybe you meant `model <- lme4::lmer(...`?

Comment: aaah, yes, of course that's what I meant. Thank you. The problem persists, though, the example is just faulty.

Comment: Please post what you are doing, in a reproducible example.

Comment: @lmo: Very good, thank you very much! Updating it worked. I have missed there was a new R version and didn't know missing updates could cause this.